# How to do an inline if-then in SQL statement syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to append my email to my @email string a bad @status is passed in.  It works without the line I commented out.  I think I'm close, but the syntax is wrong.  @override_email is null.

```
DECLARE @retval INT
DECLARE @email nvarchar(200)
DECLARE @override_email nvarchar(200) = null
DECLARE @status INT = 2
DECLARE @in_customer_id INT = 160308

SET @email = COALESCE(@override_email, (
                      SELECT
                        COALESCE(CustomerDetail.Email, '')
                        /*+ (if @status NOT IN (3,4,5) ', alex@email.com')*/
                      FROM
                        tbl_customer_detail     CustomerDetail
                      WHERE
                        CustomerDetail.customer_id = @in_customer_id))                      
select @email
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression:

```
DECLARE @retval INT
DECLARE @email nvarchar(200)
DECLARE @override_email nvarchar(200) = null
DECLARE @status INT = 2
DECLARE @in_customer_id INT = 160308

SET @email = COALESCE(@override_email, (
                      SELECT
                        COALESCE(CustomerDetail.Email, '')
                        + case when @status NOT IN (3,4,5) then ', alex@email.com' else '' end
                      FROM
                        tbl_customer_detail     CustomerDetail
                      WHERE
                        CustomerDetail.customer_id = @in_customer_id))                      
select @email
```

Comment: I swear I tried case.  I don't think I put `then`, which must have been my issue.  Has been driving me crazy.  It's making me wait 4 minutes before accepting this answer...

Comment: I've had those days, too.  Also, it looks like you could potentially be adding a comma that you may not want if there is no `@override_email` or any `CustomerDetail.Email`.

Comment: I'm using [CDO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312839) to send the emails and it seems to handle the stray `,` without issue.  I did test that though, and I'll have bigger problems if that happens lol.